# Is SQL the ''assembler'' of the NoSQL database world?

Tags: sql, nosql, fossil

I recently came across http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/tip/www/theory1.wiki by D. Richard Hipp, the developer responsible for SQLite.

it go me thinking, is Fossil the only NoSQL database that uses SQL?

Do others uses SQL as a 'High Level Scripting Language'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the article, it sounds like Fossil isn't a database any more than git is a database. Yes, it's a thing that contains data, and yes, it's backed by a database, but it seems pretty far from a database itself. So the first part of of your question basically relies on a faulty assumption. There is a database called [Friendly](http://friendlyorm.com/) which uses MySQL to store schema-less models, but it seems like an awkward bandaid sort of solution at best.

I'm certainly not familiar with all of the NoSQL options out there, but, to my knowledge, none of the well-though-of ones use SQL for anything. MongoDB and CouchDB, the two I'm most familiar with, both use Javascript as part of their query interface, though in very different ways. MongoDB has queries more like what you'd expect from a relational database: you can write an arbitrary query for all documents that match a certain set of attributes. However, unlike a relational database, there's no such thing as a join (you'll only ever get a list of distinct documents back, not compound documents) and you can write arbitrary Javascript code to select documents. CouchDB, on the other hand, does not allow arbitrary queries. Instead, you create views (which are essentially simpler key-value stores) using map/reduce functions written in Javascript and then query those views from a start key to and end key.

In both cases, the type of information being transmitted to the server to perform the query isn't well-suited for the type of problem that SQL is good at solving. The trade-off to SQL being so high-level (to use the logic of the author of the paper) is that it's only suitable for a very narrow set of problems.

Answer (score 1):

The creator of Fossil / SQLite is working and pushing [UnQL](http://www.unqlspec.org/display/UnQL/Home) as the NoSQL standard:

> UnQL means Unstructured Query Language.
>
> It's an open query language for JSON, semi-structured and document
>   databases.

It [looks](http://www.unqlspec.org/display/UnQL/Syntax+Summary) [like](http://www.unqlspec.org/display/UnQL/Example+Queries+and+Usage) a stripped down version of SQL.